# Compatible JavaScript for all versions of Bingmap Control

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Hi all I just wanted to know if we can get a general javascript for any version of bingmap control.. for ex below is an example of a version 7 of bingmaps.

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script
```

So according to this Javascript, I need to do required changes in the code as well.
So in order to savetime and energy can we have a compatible javascript which can take any versions. Like 2 ,3 ,4 ,6 or 7. Because in another 2 months bing map will release version 8 so according to that again I have to change the JavaScript and code so please give me an Optimum Solution for this may be every time they release new version just download the patch and use it. I guess changing the code every time they release a new version is the only  solution please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Versions 2-6.2 of Bing Maps no longer exist. Bing Maps releases a new map control about once every 3-4 years (not months). A map control, such as version 7 will see a lot of updates however the map script reference doesn't change. Meaning you don't need to worry about updating your code every few months. Notice how you posted this question in 2012, and it's now 2014 and there v7 is still the main Bing Maps control. There is no v8 map control at this time.